# How to implement very unusual wordpress routing structure?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, routing

Been trying the last two weeks to setup an unusual routing structure for a WordPress website but cannot manage to make it work.

Basically there is a custom post type that will get the post url based on the post category(multiple categories) eg: `site.com/movie-category/list/movie/`

In this there are also news located at: `Site.com/movie-category/news/` and for single news it will be `site.com/moviecategory/thenews`.

Then another one called e.g. `articles` which are located at: `Site.com/moviecategory/list/articles` `Site.com/moviecategory/list/articles/articlename`

A bunch of others too like `/blog/post` etc

I cannot think of a solid way to handle this without getting messy and hacky, the only way to deal with this is using a permalink redirect plugin.

I've tried a lot, I mean a lot of setups. Timber routing, WordPress rewrites, themosis, headless(this will do but we also get an api call into the `single-movie.php` (don't ask hehe)) etc etc.

I would happily accept any advice as i feel lost in this

Thank you

Comment: The core rewrite functions should be more than adequate. Can you write out a more succinct mapping of post types to URL paths?

Comment: I may not be fully understanding what you're doing here, but have you considered creating a CPT for each post type (i.e. movie, news) plus custom taxonomies (i.e. movie category) that apply to both? It would be easier to set up your URL structure that way.

Comment: I've tried editing the question to be clearer as your explanation was a single very large paragraph and it was difficult to understand what the URL structure was meant to be. It's better now but it's still not very easy to understand. Use the edit link to improve your question and help clear up any confusion or ambiguity